# How to quickly change spacing of lstlisting to use two spaces instead of four?

Tags: spacing, listings, tcolorbox, tcblisting

I'm working on some LaTeX code listings and have decided to change my spacing from four to two. The problem is that there are a ton of listings in my document (which is ~500 pages)... is there any way I can quickly reformat all of the listings to use two spaces instead of four/eight/twelve/...?

Comment: Did you use tabulators on input, or does the input contain literally four spaces you want to shorten to two?

Comment: @Skillmon They are literal spaces, i.e., "    ", that I'd like to condense into two. Though, I should be more specific - I'd like each sequence of four spaces to be halved. E.g., Eight spaces should become four, sixteen should become eight, etc.

Comment: How are the listings entered? Are they a plain text part of the `.tex` file and displayed with `\begin{lstlisting}` or `\begin{minted}` (or their tcolorbox equivalents), or are they stored in separate files and displayed with `\lstinputlisting` or `\inputminted` (or equivalent)? If they are part of the `.tex` file, is it one file or do you use separate files for chapters etc? Do you use LuaLaTeX by any chance? Do you use Linux or Mac, or Windows or Overleaf?

Comment: @Marijn They are plain pieces of text inside listing blocks. There are separate chapters with separate sections within. I use PDFLaTeX with Overleaf.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `literate` key to turn four consecutive spaces to two output spaces:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{literate={\ \ \ \ }{\space\space}{2}}

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[language=python]
if x is None:
    print('yes')
   # just a quick test that 3 spaces aren't touched
     # just a quick test that 5 spaces are touched
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Blocks of eight spaces are the same as two blocks of four spaces, the above replacement via the `literate` key will work. If you need more replacements you can simply add them, the `literate` key takes arbitrary many replacement rules as blocks of three arguments (what to replace, the replacement, the number of virtual columns the replacement will occupy).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}
\lstset
  {
    literate=
      {\ \ \ \ }{\space\space}{2}
      {yes}{no}{2}
  }

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[language=python]
if x is None:
    print('yes')
    if y is None:
        print('yes again')
   # just a quick test that 3 spaces aren't touched
     # just a quick test that 5 spaces are touched
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to use multiple “literate”s? For instance, if I want to convert all 8 spaces into four, then four into two, and so on, does it work?

Comment: @TheProgrammer Since eight spaces are two blocks of four spaces the above will work for eight spaces (you could as well just try it...). If you need more replacements you can add them, I'll edit my answer.